# Laravel orderBy Not Passing to View

Tags: laravel

I am pulling a collection from my database table using the following code.

```
$profileVisits = DB::table('recently_visited')
    ->where('visitor_id',Auth::user()->id)
    ->orderBy('times_visited', 'desc')->get();

    return view('profile.index')
        ->with([
            'user' => $user,
            'posts' => $posts,
            'profileVisits' => $profileVisits,
        ]);
```

When I dd($profileVisits) it shows the collection with the correct descending results. However, when I pull the info into my view using the following code, it doesn't descend like it's supposed to. Is the orderBy query builder being undone or something with the "return view..." code?

Code in view...

```
@if (!$user->profileVisits->count())

@else
    @foreach ($user->profileVisits as $topVisits)
        <p>{{ $topVisits->getUsername() }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

User Model:

```
public function profileVisits()
    {
        return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'recently_visited', 'visitor_id', 'profile_id');
    }

    public function addProfileVisits(User $user)
    {
        $this->profileVisits()->attach($user->id);
    }

    public function previouslyVisited(User $user)
    {
        return (bool) $this->profileVisits()->get()->where('id', $user->id)->count();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your model and its relations

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just figured it out. On the User Model, I added the orderBy instead of using it in the Controller. See below.

User Model:

```
public function profileVisits()
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'recently_visited', 'visitor_id', 'profile_id')->orderBy('times_visited', 'desc');
}
```